# InfoPath 2007 into SharePoint 2007 Form Library columns not updating

Tags: 2007, infopath, column

I have an InfoPath 2007 form that I have created as a content type and attached to a form library. The content type has some specific fields that should be populated when I have completed the form and submitted it .... but they're blank - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you promoted the fields in InfoPath ?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/add-remove-or-modify-sharepoint-library-columns-or-site-columns-HA010103003.aspx?CTT=1

Comment: Hi - I believe I have.

Comment: Sorry - didnt mean to stop there. I believe I have. I have even just done the following:

Created a New Form Library
Add the content type to that library
Re-alligned the InforPath form to that library
Re-published the form to the content type
completed the form .... nothing again

Aaaaahhhhhhh!!

Comment: Validate if your fields are promoted : open the **Tools** menu and then **Form Options**. Click on the **Property Promotion** category. You should be able to add your fields there, otherwise they won't be available in SharePoint. If that isn't working, I suggest you to publish your form in a new library just to validate.